# Significato di "tentare la carta" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Invece, in autostrada coi rododendri a dividerla, Felice sovente si era ricordato di quando la percorreva con Remo e il padre di questi
>   che **tentavano la carta** per distrarre un Felice in gramaglie. La guerra era ancora lontana...

Il ricordo di cui parla il testo fa riferimento al momento in cui Felice, ancora bambino, aveva appena perso il padre nella guerra di Spagna. Remo era un amico della sua stessa età.

Mi potreste spiegare il significato di "tentare la carta" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato alla voce "carta" di parecchi dizionari, inclusi il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non ho trovato nessuna spiegazione sul significato di questa locuzione. Una cerca su Google, però, mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di una espressione che si usa.

Infatti, sul dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli ho trovato invece l'espressione ["giocare una carta"](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/C/carta.shtml) con questo significato:

> **Fig.**: compiere un'azione particolare, mettere in atto qualcosa, fare intervenire qualcuno allo scopo d'intervenire in una situazione per produrre effetti vantaggiosi a se stessi. In senso lato, prendere una decisione abbastanza importante da modificare radicalmente una situazione, o anche azzardare, correre un rischio calcolato.

Il significato di "tentare la carta" sarebbe questo?

Anche sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000814.jpg) ho trovato questa citazione di Foscolo:

> Che  stai?  Breve è  la  vita  e  lunga  è  l’arte:  
>   a  chi  altamente  oprar  non è concesso 
>  fama tentino almen libere carte.

Ma è riportata sotto questa [definizione di "carta"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000813.jpg)

> Foglio  scritto,  stampato,  disegnato,  dipinto, miniato;  pagina  di  libro  o  di  manoscritto;  foglio di  pergamena  scritto  o  miniato.  – Al  plur.: libro, volume; le opere di uno scrittore

che non mi pare abbia molto senso nel brano sopra citato.

Comment: Tentare la carta nel senso di tentare la mossa, una metafora dal gioco delle carte.

Comment: @Gio: Quindi, il significato sarebbe un po' diverso di quello di "giocare una carta" riportato nella domanda?

Comment: La differenza fra "giocare una carta" (fare una mossa) e "tentare una carta" sta proprio nel  tentare (incertezza) contro fare (significato più neutro).

Answer (score 1):

"Tentare la carta" generalmente è accompagnato da maggiori spiegazioni, come "tentare la carta delle minacce", o "tentare la carta della via più semplice" e simili; nel tuo testo è seguito da "per distrarre", e io avverto la mancanza di "che cosa viene usato per"; forse significa qualche cosa d'altro.

In un altro contesto potrebbe essere un molto velato accenno al gioco d'azzardo. Nella frase che riporti, mi sembra senza senso compiuto (magari è un effetto voluto ma non credo).

Il "tentare la carta" viene dal giocare a carte, in cui si dispone di un limitato numero di mosse possibili (limitato appunto dalle carte che si hanno in mano), ed è in questo senso che si usa in modo figurato: serve ad esprimere l'incertezza, a volte la disperazione, di quando non s'intravvede una soluzione certamente corretta.

Comment: Concordo del tutto. Infatti si usa anche spesso "tentare l'ultima carta" per indicare un tentativo disperato in "zona Cesarini", per così dire...